# Is the integral of an Ito process still an Ito process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Assume $r(t)$ is an Ito diffusion:
$$dr_t = \mu_tdt + \sigma_tdW_t$$
Then, define the following process:
$$X_t = \int_0^tr(s)ds$$
Is $X_t$ still an Ito diffusion?

Comment: What means Ito diffusion? (Is Itô diffusion  a solution to a specific type of stochastic differential equation ?)

Comment: Yes, it means that it is solution of the Ito SDE, as $r_t$ is by assumption

Comment: The question is about $X_t$, can you write down $X_t$ as the solution of an Ito SDE, i.e. in the same form as $r(t)$?

Comment: I know. Indeed, this is first step.

Comment: Yes, then put it inside the integral. The second step would be applying the Fubini theorem which I guess is not allowed in this case...

Comment: In general, $X$ is not a diffusion, actually it is not even Markov. The simplest example might be *integrated Brownian motion* (when $\mu_t=0$ and $\sigma_t=1$ for every $t$), also called Langevin process by some authors, defined as $X_t=x+\int_0^tW_sds$. For an introduction to the study of this process (in French), see A. Lachal. Application de la théorie des excursions à l’intégrale du mouvement brownien. In Séminaire de Probabilités XXXVII, volume 1832 of Lecture Notes in Math., pages 109–195. Springer, Berlin, 2003.

Comment: Thank you @Did. That is what I was guessing but I had not enough references to support my intuition, now I have.

Answer (score 0):

$X_t$ is of finite variation.  Per conventional definitions, it is not a diffusion process.

The integral defining $X_t$ is well defined in the classical sense path-by-path.